# COQ gets wrong by proving "forall n:nat, ( n <= 0) -> n=0"

Tags: coq

Can someone explain me the following - apparently wrong - COQ derivation?

```
Theorem test: forall n:nat,  ( n <= 0) -> n=0.  
intros n H.  
elim H.  
auto.
```

*COQ answer:*

```
1 subgoal  
n : nat  
H : n <= 0 

=================  
forall m : nat, n <= m -> n = m -> n = S m
```

Comment: what do mean "wrong" ? nothing is wrong here.

Comment: Coq didn't get it wrong, you got it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`le` (`<=`) has two constructors. In `n <= 0` both (somehow) could apply:

```
Inductive le (n : nat) : nat -> Prop :=
    le_n : n <= n
  | le_S : forall m : nat, n <= m -> n <= S m
```

`auto` in your proof solves the first goal / case. The second is unprovable. You should do induction on `n` to prove the theorem:

```
Theorem test: forall n, n <= 0 -> n = 0.
intros n H.
induction n.
reflexivity.
inversion H. Qed.
```

or you could use `inversion H` tactic (not `elim`):

```
Theorem test: forall n, n <= 0 -> n = 0.
intros n H.
inversion H.
auto. Qed.
```

Comment: I still don't understand the logic behind COQs derivation of this unprovable subgoal.

Comment: `elim` is very basic tactic. It forgets that in the `H` assumption `0 <= m` the lhs is `0` not `n`.

Answer (score 1):

When using induction on a predicate, you usually need to make sure the arguments to the predicate are variables and not terms. You do so by adding some equations. You also usually need to make sure those variables are distinct and that there aren't any unnecessary hypotheses or quantifiers before the predicate.

```
Goal forall n1, n1 <= 0 -> n1 = 0.

assert (H1 : forall n1 n2, n1 <= n2 -> n2 = 0 -> n1 = 0).
induction 1 as [| n2 H1 H2].
intros H1.
eapply H1.
intros H3.
discriminate.

intros n1 H2.
eapply H1.
eapply H2.
eapply eq_refl.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around: your original goal doesn't imply the unprovable goal; it's the unprovable goal that implies the original.

The goal

```
A : B
_____
C
```

is equivalent to the sequent

```
A : B |- C.
```

When proving something interactively in Coq, you are building a sequent tree from bottom to top. Here's an example.

```
   -------------------- apply H
   P : Prop, H : P |- P
   -------------------- intro H
    P : Prop |- P -> P
-------------------------- intro P
|- forall P : Prop, P -> P
```

Of course, when moving backwards to a proof, you can make a wrong move.

```
            ?
      ------------- ?
      P : Prop |- P
   -------------------- clear H
   P : Prop, H : P |- P
   -------------------- intro H
    P : Prop |- P -> P
-------------------------- intro P
|- forall P : Prop, P -> P
```

You can learn more about sequent calculus from all over the internet.